# Проставить индексы в глобальном скоупе элементам внутри ngFor

Tags: angular2, angular5

Я использую функцию trackByIndex чтобы проставить индексы элементам внутри цикла ngFor:

```
trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
  return index;
}
```

Вот сокращенный пример моей конструкции:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  {{ i, comment.text }}
  <div *ngFor="let answer of comment.answers; let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">{{ j, answer.text }}</div>
</div>
```

Но когда первый ngFor отрисовывает несколько элементов, то во вложенном цикле итерация (j) начинается заново.

Вот короткое представление для большей наглядности, как отрисовываются и итерируются объекты:

```
"comment 1": {
    "answer 1",
    "answer 2"
},
"comment 2": {
    "answer 1", // должен быть индекс 3
    "answer 2" // должен быть индекс 4
}
```

Проблема в том, что итерации происходят в локальных скоупах, поэтому в каждом из объектов она начинается сначала. Как я могу проставить индексы объектам answer через все объекты comment?

Искренне надеюсь, что понятно изложил проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Возможен такой вариант:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  {{ i, comment.text }}
  <div *ngFor="let answer of comment.answers; let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">{{ answer.text }} {{counter++}}</div>
</div>
```

В этом компоненте определяется переменная счетчика counter.

```
counter: number = 0;
```

Для ее увеличения и вывода значения применяются метод increment. Это если я правильно понял суть вопроса.

Comment: Так ведь тоже неверно получится?

Comment: Если ему нужен счетчик и вывести к каждому элементу число согласно свое очереди, то можно.. а иначе нет, глобально скоуп в данной директиве, не представляю.. только переменная объявленная внутри самого класса

Answer (score 0):

А может, просто использовать css?

https://codesandbox.io/s/52x312ooy4?module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <ul class="nth-reset">
      <li *ngFor="let x of data; let i = index">
        Section {{i+1}}
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let y of x" class="nth-inc">
            {{y}} is item #<span class="nth"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .nth-reset { counter-reset: nth 0 }
    .nth-inc {counter-increment: nth }
    .nth:after { content: counter(nth) }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    ["1-A", "1-B", "1-C"],
    ["2-A", "2-B"],
    ["3-A", "3-B", "3-C", "3-D"]
  ];
}
```